# AssertionError: Class RegisterSerializer missing "Meta" attribute

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting this error "AssertionError: Class RegisterSerializer missing "Meta" attribute" when using Django Rest API. I did make all migrations but can't figure out how to fix this error. The /register part of this application is where I am getting the error.

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from rest_framework_jwt.serializers import User

from .models import Movie


class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('pk', 'name', 'description', 'year', 'rating')


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )


password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, style={'input_type': 'password'},
                                 validators=[validate_password])
password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, style={'input_type': 'password'}, required=True)


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'password', 'password2', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    extra_kwargs = {
        'first_name': {'required': True},
        'last_name': {'required': True}
    }


def validate(self, attrs):
    if attrs['password'] != attrs['password2']:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": "Password fields didn't match."})

    return attrs


def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User.objects.create(
        username=validated_data['username'],
        email=validated_data['email'],
        first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
        last_name=validated_data['last_name'])

    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()

    return user
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token
from api import views
from api.views import RegisterView

urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    path('', views.movie_list),
    url(r'^api/movies/$', views.movie_list),
    url(r'^api/movies/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.getMovie),
    path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='auth_register'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


# Create your models here.
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=360)
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    rating = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)

    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def created(self):
        self.created_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def updated(self):
        self.updated_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import status, generics
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .serializers import *
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, AllowAny


@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def movie_list(request):
    permission_classes = IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
    if request.method == 'GET':
        movies = Movie.objects.all()
        serializer = MovieSerializer(movies, context={'request': request}, many=True)
        return Response({'data': serializer.data})

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = MovieSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def getMovie(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a movie instance.
    """
    try:
        movie = Movie.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Movie.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = MovieSerializer(movie, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = MovieSerializer(movie, data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        movie.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)


class RegisterView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
```

I have tried some suggestions from other posts on here but all of those did not apply to my current issue. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Isn't your indentation wrong for the RegisterSerializer?

Comment: I think there there seems a misuse of your RegisterSerializer, indeed you inherit from ModelSerializer in which you did not set any Meta and model linked within. Therefore what you might want is to use the inheritance from Serializer class instead.